# Limit threads for Windows Workflow

Tags: c#, .net, performance, workflow-foundation-4

I am developing an application that uses Windows Workflow. One area of the workflow uses a Parallel.ForEach activity that runs a AsyncCodeActivity. You can see this in the screenshot below. The RunPolicyWorkflow Activity is an AsyncCodeActivity.

[image]

From what I understand from the Windows Workflow documentation is that this will create new threads as needed to operate on the collection that is being enumerated in the ParalleForEach Activity.

I have around 16000 items in the Parallel Loop. Inside the loop (during the RunPolicyWorkflow Activity) I am doing a little CPU work, but most of the time is spent saving the results to a SQL Server Instance. When using Resource Monitor to keep an eye on my process, I noticed that there were around 2,000 threads in this process that was running the workflow.

It looks like my application is getting slower the more threads it creates. My computer only has 8 logical processors so I'm pretty sure this isn't great optimization.

Does anyone know of a way to limit the amount of threads that Windows Workflow is creating? Or does anyone have any suggestions on a way that this could be done better? All the items in the Parallel loop are independent from each other and I want to process all of the items in the collection (16000) as fast as possible. Initially Its processing at about 300 items per minute but lows down to about 60 items per minute as the thread count gets higher and more items have been processed.

Comment: Are you sure sql-server can handle that load? Those threads are not all waiting for transactions to be commited on sql-server?

Comment: A simple search gave http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365049/restrict-number-of-threads-in-parallel-foreach-in-windows-workflow-foundation-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example activity that throttles the parallel activities.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee620808(v=vs.100).aspx